# How to run a command in Docker using custom arguments?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

How to run a command in Docker using custom arguments?

I'm trying to run a command that causes django to rotate using an environment variable through an argument in the act of creating the server.

Thank you very much for your attention.

I need to run the command in this format to work.

```
# VAR=enviroment_name python manage.py migrate --database=01_sistema
```

docker

```
docker exec 24e2b5c60a79 VAR=enviroment_name python manage.py migrate --database=01_sistema
```

Error

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"VAR=enviroment_name\": executable
>   file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: `docker exec -e VAR=enviroment_name 24e2b5c60a79 python manage.py migrate --database=01_sistema`

Answer (score 0):

In bash you set environment by appending `key=value` to command. However, this is not the case for docker. You can pass environment to docker exec by adding argument `-e key=value` (can be specified multiple times). In your case, that is

```
docker exec -e VAR=enviroment_name 24e2b5c60a79 python manage.py migrate --database=01_sistema
```